# calculator doesn't process two operator equations

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm working on a calculator app and have all the functionality down. The only issue is that when I input an equation that contains two arithmetic operators, it malfunctions. For example, if I input "2 + √9" it returns 3 and if I input "√9 + 2", it force closes and says "invalid double √9". Please help.

## ScientificCalculator.java

```
String prevAnswer = "";
TextView formulascreen;
TextView resultscreen;
String formuladisplay = "";
String resultdisplay = "";
String result = "";
String operator;
DecimalFormat res = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.######");

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scientific_calculator, container, false);

    formulascreen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.formulaTextView);
    updateformuladisplay();

    resultscreen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    updateresultdisplay();

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn6).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn7).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn8).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn9).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickNumber(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnSqrt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClicksqrt(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnClear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickClear(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnDel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickDel(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickOperator(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickOperator(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnDivide).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickOperator(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickOperator(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnEquals).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickEquals(v);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.btnPrevAns).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickAns(v);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onClickEquals(View view) {

        getResult();
        updateresultdisplay();

}

private boolean getResult() {

    if (operator.equals("")) return false;

    String[] operation = formuladisplay.split(Pattern.quote(operator));

    if (operation.length < 2) return false;

    if (operator.equals("√")) {

        result = String.valueOf(res.format(sqrtOp(operator, operation[1])));
        resultdisplay = result;
        prevAnswer = result;
        result = "";

    }

    else {

        result = String.valueOf(res.format(simpleOp(operation[0], operation[1], operator)));
        resultdisplay = result;
        prevAnswer = result;
        result = "";

    }

    return true;

}

public double simpleOp(String a, String b, String op) {

    switch (op) {

        case "+":
            return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);

        case "-":
            return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);

        case "x":
            return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);

        case "÷":
            return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);

        default:
            return -1;

    }

}

private void updateformuladisplay() {

    formulascreen.setText(formuladisplay);

}

private void updateresultdisplay() {

    resultscreen.setText(resultdisplay);

}

public void onClicksqrt(View view) {

    Button b = (Button) view;

    operator = b.getText().toString();

    formuladisplay += operator;
    updateformuladisplay();

}

public void onClickDel(View view) {

    if (formuladisplay.length() >= 1) {

        formuladisplay = formuladisplay.substring(0, formuladisplay.length() - 1);
        updateformuladisplay();

    }

}

private void clear() {

    formuladisplay = "";
    resultdisplay = "";

}

public void onClickClear(View view) {

    clear();
    updateformuladisplay();
    updateresultdisplay();

}

public void onClickNumber(View view) {

    //if (!(result.equals(""))) {

      //  clear();
        //updateformuladisplay();

    //}

    Button b = (Button) view;

    if (formuladisplay.length() >= 0 && formuladisplay.length() <= 17) {

        formuladisplay += b.getText();
        updateformuladisplay();

    }

    else {

        updateformuladisplay();

    }

}

public void onClickOperator(View view) {

    Button b = (Button) view;

    operator = b.getText().toString();

    formuladisplay += operator;
    updateformuladisplay();

}

public double sqrtOp(String op, String a) {

    switch (op) {

        case "√":
            return Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(a));

        default:
            return -1;

    }

}

public void onClickAns(View view) {

    Button b = (Button) view;

    if (formuladisplay.length() >= 0 && formuladisplay.length() <= 10) {

        formuladisplay += prevAnswer;
        updateformuladisplay();

    }

    else {

        updateformuladisplay();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You have to use split the expression in sub expression then calculate the Mathematical calculaation

Comment: @DixitPanchal Could you please guide me on how I can implement it in my current code? Sorry, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stack data-structure to calculate the expression .Try this simple class
You can add your sqrt operation in regex

> private static final String operators = "-+/*";

And add sqrt operation in evaluatePostfix method.

```
public class InfixPostfixEvaluator {

        /**
         * Operators in reverse order of precedence.
         */
        private static final String operators = "-+/*";
        private static final String operands = "0123456789";

        public int evalInfix(String infix) {
                return evaluatePostfix(convert2Postfix(infix));
        }

        public String convert2Postfix(String infixExpr) {
                char[] chars = infixExpr.toCharArray();
                Stack&lt;Character&gt; stack = new Stack&lt;Character&gt;();
                StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(infixExpr.length());

                for (char c : chars) {
                        if (isOperator(c)) {
                                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                                        if (operatorGreaterOrEqual(stack.peek(), c)) {
                                                out.append(stack.pop());
                                        } else {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                                stack.push(c);
                        } else if (c == '(') {
                                stack.push(c);
                        } else if (c == ')') {
                                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                                        out.append(stack.pop());
                                }
                                if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                                        stack.pop();
                                }
                        } else if (isOperand(c)) {
                                out.append(c);
                        }
                }
                while (!stack.empty()) {
                        out.append(stack.pop());
                }
                return out.toString();
        }

        public int evaluatePostfix(String postfixExpr) {
                char[] chars = postfixExpr.toCharArray();
                Stack&lt;Integer&gt; stack = new Stack&lt;Integer&gt;();
                for (char c : chars) {
                        if (isOperand(c)) {
                                stack.push(c - '0'); // convert char to int val
                        } else if (isOperator(c)) {
                                int op1 = stack.pop();
                                int op2 = stack.pop();
                                int result;
                                switch (c) {
                                case '*':
                                        result = op1 * op2;
                                        stack.push(result);
                                        break;
                                case '/':
                                        result = op2 / op1;
                                        stack.push(result);
                                        break;
                                case '+':
                                        result = op1 + op2;
                                        stack.push(result);
                                        break;
                                case '-':
                                        result = op2 - op1;
                                        stack.push(result);
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
                return stack.pop();
        }
        private int getPrecedence(char operator) {
                int ret = 0;
                if (operator == '-' || operator == '+') {
                        ret = 1;
                } else if (operator == '*' || operator == '/') {
                        ret = 2;
                }
                return ret;
        }
        private boolean operatorGreaterOrEqual(char op1, char op2) {
                return getPrecedence(op1) &gt;= getPrecedence(op2);
        }

        private boolean isOperator(char val) {
                return operators.indexOf(val) &gt;= 0;
        }

        private boolean isOperand(char val) {
                return operands.indexOf(val) &gt;= 0;
        }

}
```

For details read http://willcode4beer.com/design.jsp?set=evalInfix

http://www.java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/stacks/infix-expression/

Comment: Will this also work for when an equation has a sqrt operation at the start? Like "√4 - 1"?

Comment: yes. you should use parenthesis notation like sqrt (4-1). see second link in answer

Comment: Alright thanks. Gonna read up on it, implement it and I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: It seems that the code doesn't work for decimal numbers since the stack requires an int variable. Any solution to this?

Comment: you can update your result value and stack also with double

Comment: It gives me an error saying that the push function requires an int. Sorry if these seem like very basic questions. I'm fairly new to Android development

Comment: extra efforts required to support double value. You need to store value in stack as String rather than character. Update your switch case with string and also update equality check with strings class equals method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113822/discussion-between-dayem-saeed-and-uskmobility).